# On-board computer / data handling system of Rosetta - details?

Tags: flight-computer, data-storage, rosetta

I seek detailed information on the computer and/or data handling system of Rosetta.

- Who manufactured it?
- What type(s) of CPU is used?

  - What kind of architecture does it belong to and at what frequency does it operate?
- What is the operating system?
- **How much data can the system store?**

  - What types of storage does it include (RAM, ROM, disks, whatever)?
- **What are the I/O rate of the various storage devices?**
- Is there any buffering system? (At what rate can the data be send back to Earth?)

Comment: That's a lot of questions.

Comment: I would like to know some details about the computer, yes, but I care most about the memory speeds. I could use this as a reference for something I am working on. However, even ignoring the speeds, there is not even good information on the computer in general as far as I can tell ... or I am looking at the wrong places.

Comment: What about this one I just stumbled across? http://www.spyr.ch/ps/ads/qm/usermanual.html

Comment: I'd like to add what language are they programming in, without revealing what I hope the answer is (or is not).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Orbiter

The Solid State Mass Memory (SSMM) is 25 Gbit (about 3 GByte) with a 5Mbps data rate.

> The telemetry rate shall be switchable between 8 bps and 65536 bps

and

> The bus throughput shall be minimal 131 kbps.
>
> The SSMM shall support an input data rate of up to 5 Mbps useable data (physical data rate excluding IEEE-1355 protocol overhead)
>
> The telecommand rate shall be switchable between at least 4 bit rates, i.e. 7.81 (4000/2 ), 250, 1000 and 2000 bps.
>
> The usable memory size shall be at least 1MWord RAM and 512 KWords EEPROM for each of 4 processors, and 512KWords PROM (redundant) accessible from each processor.
>
> The SSMM shall have a size of at least 25 Gbit at end of life taking into account failures in memory cells.

[Found Here](ftp://ftp.estec.esa.nl/pub2/sci-spd/roserid/System%20Requirements%20Specification,%20RO-EST-RS-2001%20issue%206.pdf)

### Lander

> The Central Interface Unit (CIU) provides the communication among the units of the Lander. This is a synchronous, serial data transmission channel with the transmission rate of 32kbit/s.

and

> The Harris RTX2010 processor has been selected for the DPU boards

Note that there are two Data Process Units (DPU) in warm-redundant mode. Also note that this is a 16 bit processor.

[Found Here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/234265387_Embedded_Computer_System_on_the_Rosetta_Spacecraft)

> Data: 235 Mbit during primary mission, 65 Mbit during each subsequent
> 60 h period

and

> Data rate 16 kbit/sec

also

> central computing and data storage capability (2x2 Mbyte, RAM, EEPROM)

[Found Here](http://www.planetaryprobe.eu/IPPW7/proceedings/IPPW7%20Proceedings/Presentations/Session7B/pr395.pdf)

Comment: And also one of its cameras (i think osiris) has 4M pixels resolution, was quite big at that time (2004)

Comment: To add another reference - some info can be found [here](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1997ESASP.409..133D/0000135.000.html)